# drupal create content "add more" field

Tags: drupal, view, cck, addition

how do i make that in the creating screen of content type i will be have option to add single/multiply values? so if use have field: type your friend name:

he can choose to type one friend and there is option add more and then another field will open to him so he can add more friends names?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Navigate to:

Administer->Content Management->Content Types

- Click Manage Fields on the type you want to change
- Next click the configure link beside the field you want to have an "Add More" for
- Finally under Global Settings change the "Number of values:" setting to unlimited.
- Now when you add a content item of that type there will be a "Add More" or "Add Another Item" link provided.